# workarounds for BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION's missing ternary operator in initialization lists

Tags: c++, exception, boost, initialization-list

I often end up using ternaries that throw exceptions which may seem a bit weird but save the day in initialization lists (hence that helps for writing sound constructors, hence that helps for RAII, ...). E.g. if the argument `a` is a `smart_ptr<>` that we want non `nullptr`, then I could initiate a member like

```
member(a ? a->get_something() : throw exception())
```

I think this is a valid, legit & safe use (do tell me if this is not).

I recently switched to boost::exception, and unfortunately `condition ? ret_value : BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(exception())` doesn't compile (since the compiler cannot reify `typeof(ret_value)` and `void`).

Are there any work-arounds better than creating a whole new private static method and putting an `if` inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly valid C++, but many compilers won't see BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION as a throw-expression, but just a regular void-type expression. As the standard requires that either the void-type expression is a throw expression, or both branches are of type void, the compiler rejects the ternary expression.

The typical workaround is to use the comma operator:

```
condition ? ret_value : (BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(exception()), decltype(ret_value){})
```

You can, of course, replace the part after the comma with any expression of the correct type, and you can be certain that it won't be used.

Comment: `decltype<ret_value>{}`? `decltype` is an operator, are you thinking of `std::declval`? In that case, that won't work either: `std::declval` can only appear in unevaluated contexts.

Comment: `decltype(ret_value)` will return the type of `ret_value`, the following `{}` will default-construct a value of that type. If you know the type of `ret_value`, it's usually a better idea to provide an actual value. I just used `decltype` here to be general.

Comment: You are correct. I somehow typoed that even though I had spelled it correctly just minutes before.

Answer (score 0):

> I think this is a valid, legit & safe use (do tell me if this is not).

It is not, imo. You can't and should not defend against any crappy arguments you could get. Because if you would, you would have to check for *everything*. Any `size_t` function argument would have to be checked against if it contains a sensible value. Any `char*` would have to be checked if it is NULL or not, and if not you'd have to check if it is zero-delimited. You would have to apply thousands of checks throughout your classes and functions to check for things that are unlikely to happen but could happen in some weird circumstances.

Consider `std::strlen` and `std::string::string(char const*)`: both demand that the argument be a non-null pointer to a null-terminated char string. No checks applied, if you pass NULL, you get UB.

There are many cases where functions guarantee to return non-null pointers. If such a result is passed to your constructor (or `strlen`, for that matter), the extra check is a waste of time and programming effort.
In short: don't test for null pointers, instead just demand non-null pointers. It's the responsibility of the clients to pass correct arguments, because only the client code knows if it is necessary to check for nullpointers, and it has to handle the nullpointer case anyway, either by checking before the call or by catching the exception.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that approach. Sometimes there are unforeseen circunstances that just warrant exceptions. Maybe the `shared_ptr<>` was a too simple example, but the conditional itself could be complicated or tricky enough so that the caller is not sure how to do it (say testing if a matrix is full-rank or not). Also, this is not an external facing API but a large critical project (critical in the cannot-fail sense) and I've learned not to trust myself with unchecked pre-conditions: One day it doesn't work but looks like it does and disaster looms. I guess that's a taste thing...

Comment: If the conditional is tricky, it means that the ternary expression will be complex enough that it should be put in a `initMemberFromA`-function of its own. Whether it's an external API or not is not relevant - you have to take the same care on calling internal APIs as on calling standard library functionality. And for `cannot-fail` modules there are the same must-haves than for any other modules: extensive unit-testing and good code reviews. If you still want to check the arguments, do so in a function. Initializers should be single expressions to maintain readability.

Comment: How about this?
`m_det(a->isFullRank() ? a->determinant() : throw exception())
, m_X(m_det->isPureImaginary() ? m_det->imaginaryPart() : throw exception())
`
Now the test is potentially complicated, yet readable. Plus I've chained another potentially complicated test to it, yet it still uses initialization lists and one can go on and on. In the grand scheme of things you probably are right but still I know I'm sloppy which is why I like to give myself additional toddlers bars.

Comment: I wouldn't call that very readable. How about this: `m_det(getDeterminant(a)), m_X(getPureImaginary(m_det))` And perhaps `m_X` and `m_det` should be stuffed together into a common subobject if they are so closely related, but that depends much on the context.